# How to create path for all files in public folder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want all files in public folder to have url route `/static`. For example a request to `/static/foo.html` would be served `public/foo.html`.

It seems possible to do this with with a catch all route, but that does not seem to be a very good solution.

Is there a Rails way to define the url path for the public folder?

Rails 6

Answer (score 0):

ActionDispatch checks if a requested file is in the public directory, and will send it if it exists. This happens before rails analyzes the url to determine the rack endpoint.

If you put a file in public/static/foo.html, it will be served with the url /static/foo.html.

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but that wouldn't work for favicon and robots and probably not packs and packs-test. I was looking for something more elegant.

Comment: It can be done in your nginx configuration, by mapping urls, but no 'elegant' rails config can achieve this